creating a Google Action Console project fails
Based on this Home Assistant tutorial I'm trying to create a project within Google Action Console.
When I try to do this I get the following error:
error message
I have tried this now with several broswer on several devices to various times and days. Always get the same error. Based on the message on the top it seems that something does happen in the background as the number of project I can create decrease everyt ime. But I'm not able to see those projects, let alone configure them.
I have contacted Google Support but they only said I should use Google Home Developer Console but this does not provide me with the options I need for the tutorial. The other recommendation was to contact the community for help, so here I am.
Any idea on how I can create a project or view the ones which have apparently being created?
Regards,
Sebastian
Tried creating a project with several devices and several browser to various times and days.
I would expect a project to be created and for me to configure it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can try using the following codelab to get an understanding of how to publish a cloud service that manages a virtual smart device,  then build a smart home Action and connect it to the Assistant.
You can also  refer to the following link to get an understanding about how to manage projects in the Actions Console.
Also, always try refraining from using a GSuite/Workspace account with Google Actions Console. It is recommended to make use of a regular account.
